# module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'pdf'

Tags: pdf, pypdf

```
import PyPDF2

def copiar_anotaciones(pagina_fuente, pagina_destino):
    for anotacion in pagina_fuente['/Annots']:
        anotacion_ref = anotacion.getObject()
        if '/Dest' in anotacion_ref:
            destino = anotacion_ref['/Dest']
            if isinstance(destino, PyPDF2.generic.ArrayObject) and len(destino) >= 2:
                pagina_referencia = destino[0]
                if isinstance(pagina_referencia, PyPDF2.generic.NumberObject):
                    pagina_referencia = int(pagina_referencia)
                    destino[0] = pagina_destino
                    pagina_destino['/Annots'].append(anotacion_ref)

def alternar_paginas(pdf1_path, pdf2_path, output_path):
    pdf1 = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf1_path)
    pdf2 = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf2_path)

    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    # Con esta variable asumo que ambos PDFs tienen la misma cantidad de páginas
    num_pages = min(len(pdf1.pages), len(pdf2.pages))

    for i in range(num_pages):
        pagina1 = pdf1.pages[i]
        pagina2 = pdf2.pages[i]

        nueva_pagina = PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.createBlankPage(                    # Linea del error !!!!!!
            width=pagina1.mediaBox.getWidth() + pagina2.mediaBox.getWidth(),
            height=max(pagina1.mediaBox.getHeight(), pagina2.mediaBox.getHeight())
        )

        nueva_pagina.mergeTranslatedPage(pagina1, 0, 0)
        nueva_pagina.mergeTranslatedPage(pagina2, pagina1.mediaBox.getWidth(), 0)

        copiar_anotaciones(pagina1, nueva_pagina)
        copiar_anotaciones(pagina2, nueva_pagina)

        pdf_writer.add_page(nueva_pagina)

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        pdf_writer.write(output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf_ingles_path = "Learning_SQL_Generate,_Manipulate,_and_Retrieve_Data-bibis.ir.pdf"
    pdf_espanol_path = "ilovepdf_merged (1).pdf"
    pdf_resultante_path = "Learning_SQL_Espanol_Ingles5.pdf"

    alternar_paginas(pdf_ingles_path, pdf_espanol_path, pdf_resultante_path)
```

Necesito arreglar el error

Answer (score 0):

`PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject` needs to be `PyPDF2.PageObject`.

Also, you should use `pypdf`. PyPDF2 is deprecated (see README: https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/).